# adding explicit import for collectors in java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have been using streams and lambdas in my java code and also list and other data structures for that i have added the two import statements in my java code that are

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

Mine query is that when I have added the first import ending with wild card do I need to add the second import of collectors explicitly or the should I remove the import of collectors one and the first one will work for all please advise.

Comment: FYI, as of Java 16, if collecting to a `List` you no longer need to refer to `Collectors`. The `Stream` interface gained a [`toList`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) method. So `myStream.collect( Collectors.toList() )` becomes `myStream.toList()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) class in your code you have to import it in your code with the *SingleTypeImportDeclaration* `import java.util.stream.Collectors` or the *TypeImportOnDemandDeclaration* `import java.util.stream.*`, you can check [jls-7.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5) for further informations.

The *TypeImportOnDemandDeclaration* `import java.util.*` causes the simple names of all public classes and interfaces declared in the package `java.util` to be available within the class and interface declarations of the compilation unit, so excluding the `Collectors` class instead declared in the package `java.util.stream`.